# ios 7: UIBarButton with Custom image and title programmatically

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am struggling to create UIBarButtonItem with custom image and title with proper insets of both image and title. Please refer the image and help me out from this[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIBarButtonItem appearance], you can set changes on the appearance of all your barbutton items. In case you want to change insets, you could use [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

There are also a plenty of customization you can perform. Refere to the UIAppearance protocol for more information.

Wish it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can init the UIBarButtonItem with a custom view that has both image and text. Here's a sample that uses a `UIButton`, also you can use a `UIView`.

```
UIImage *chatImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"privateChat.png"];

UIButton *chatButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[chatButton setBackgroundImage:chatImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[chatButton setTitle:@"Private Chat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
chatButton.frame = (CGRect) {
    .size.width = 100,
    .size.height = 30,
};

UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:chatButton] autorelease];
self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barButton];
```

Comment: title is not coming as expected..anyways thanks for giving an update

Comment: you can make your own view, for example make a view with 50X50 size, and put image and label in it